# how to nsupdate remotely?

Tags: security, bind

I have BIND as a DNS server, what I want is to let this server to allow me to add or remove records to a zone without manually editing the zone file and I want to do this remotely.

Is this updating need a key or something like that or can I do it using ssh connection like this:

```
ssh user@remote "nsupdate ..... " ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it:
actually it needs a key:
creating the key:

```
dnssec-keygen -a HMAC-MD5 -b 128 -n HOST example.com.
```

editing conf. file:

```
// TSIG Key
key "example.com." {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "THE KEY GENERATED ABOVE";
};
zone "example.com" IN {
   type master;
   file "example.com.zone";
   allow-update{ key "example.com."; };
};
```

give the named authorization to the /var/named folder:

```
 # chown -R named:named /var/named
 # find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
 # find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

I experimented with this a bit ago, and you can establish a dynamic zone in bind to do this.  However, if I recall you'll lose the ability to directly edit the zone and have to update this zone using the dynamic update commands.

I also believe that you can establish a key to prevent unauthorized access to this facility as well.

The solution I commonly see now is that dynamic zones are handled using Windows AD/DNS mechanisms or even third party networking solutions.

Comment: You can edit dynamic zones in bind with the help of the `freeze` and `thaw` subcommands of `rndc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a key by allowing specific hosts to perform the update, for example 127.0.0.1, or the private network of your DNS server, e.g.

```
zone "example.com" {
  type master;
  file "/var/lib/bind/db.example.com";
  allow-update {
    127.0.0.1;
    192.168.33/24;
    192.168.42/24;
  };
};
```

As you mentioned, you can also add `allow-update { key "example.com." }` to use a keyfile. However I would recommend a more secure key than 128bit HMAC-MD5. For example, try:

```bsh
# RSA-SHA256
dnssec-keygen -a RSASHA256 -b 2046 -n ZONE example.com.

# Elliptic Curve
dnssec-keygen -a ED25519 -n ZONE example.com.
```

Side-note: I believe dynamic zones should live in `/var/lib/bind`, not `/etc/bind`.

The manual notes you should not update dynamic zone config "by hand":

> Zones that are under dynamic control via nsupdate or a DHCP server should not be edited by  hand.  Manual  edits could conflict with dynamic updates and cause data to be lost.

You can save dynamic updates to disk by using rndc, for example:

```bsh
rndc freeze example.com.
rndc sync example.com.
rndc thaw example.com.
```